# navigator.online show iframe and when offline show image

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Need help to display a cached image (service worker) when no internet connection, in place of my iframe - herewith my not working attempt in fiddle

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/hrax5doq/10/>
```

In fiddle I used an external image location just as an example but how do I use a cached imaged url in my code

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```js
if (window.navigator.onLine) {
d.innerHTML = '<iframe id="iframe" src="https://maps.google.it/maps?q=Inprint Printers,25+Watermeyer+st,eMalahleni,Mpumalanga,1035&output=embed" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
} else {
 d.innerHTML = '<img scr="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/User-Chaza93-Offline.png">';
}
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  scrolling: no;
  marginheight: 0;
  marginwidth: 0;
  frameborder: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: Thanxs, will try it in my application one problem my iframe needs to be in html as I use variables in my url